# Actions on Google Push Notifications with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, push-notification, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm struggling through the official [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates/notifications) of how to setup push notifications in Actions on Google. I did find this Github project [here](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actionssdk-updates-nodejs).

However I'm still unclear on the exact steps of setting up an intent in dialogflow to acheive this. I am using webhooks for all of my intents currently.

**Question #1:**

On the official documentation it talks about referencing the event `actions_intent_PERMISSION`. However, I have an intent set up for this event already when i ask to get the users location. Do I set up a separate intent to handle the user permission for push notifications, or do I somehow handle both permission grants in a single intent?

**Question #2:**

How many intents do I need to properly execute this user flow?

- DF: "do you want be notified of severe weather"
- User: "yes"
- DF: "i'll need to get permission to send you notifications, is that ok?"
- List "yes"
- *** how many intents occur here ***

What I'm hoping to find is a more concrete example of how to set up a push notification on google actions using dialogflow.

Comment: Have you tried the [Dialogflow](https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-updates-nodejs) equivalent of that sample?

Comment: I didn't see this one, I'm going to look it over thank you for the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nick Felker had a good link, I'm not sure how I missed this example, but it is a much more clear example of how to build out push notifications in dialogflow with Nodejs fulfillment.

Thank you for the link:
https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-updates-nodejs/blob/master/functions/index.js